# Android EditTextPreference - how to disable one of the buttons in the default dialog

Tags: android, preferences

I am extending the EditTextPreference class and want to disable one of the default buttons in some situations when showing the dialog.

I got a hint form this answer: [EditTextPreference Disable Buttons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4762027/edittextpreference-disable-buttons) about how to access the buttons in the default dialog BUT for some reason getDialog() returns null in all callback methods of the EditTextPreference class.

To be more specific I tried overriding following:
onPrepareDialogBuilder(Builder builder) 
onBindDialogView(View view) 
onAttachedToActivity()
onBindView(View view)

Is it possible at all to affect some of the buttons in the default dialog before showing it (or right after showing it - would work for me too)?

Update:
I found a (bit counter-intuitive) solution:
just override the showDialog() method of the DialogPreference class like this:

```
  @Override
  protected void showDialog(Bundle state) {
    super.showDialog(state);
    Dialog dlg = getDialog();
    ...
  }
```

The getDialog() method returns a non-null value here and you can manipulate the buttons.

Thank you

Vasil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question - I found a (bit counter-intuitive) solution: just override the showDialog() method of the DialogPreference class like this:

```
  @Override
  protected void showDialog(Bundle state) {
    super.showDialog(state);
    Dialog dlg = getDialog();
    ...
  }
```

The getDialog() method returns a non-null value here and you can manipulate the buttons.